# Separating development/staging/production media buckets on S3 in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

We are currently using AWS S3 buckets  as a storage for media files in a Django 1.11 project (using `S3BotoStorage` from `django-storages` library). The relevant code is here:

```py
# storage.py

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class MediaRootS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """Storage for uploaded media files."""
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    custom_domain = domain(settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

```py
# common_settings.py

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storage.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
MEDIA_URL = "//media.example.com/"
```

```py
# models.py
import os
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string


def upload_to_unique_filename(instance, filename):
    try:
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    except Exception:
        extension = ""
    now = timezone.now()

    return f'resume/{now.year}/{now.month}/{uuid.uuid4()}{extension}'


class Candidate(models.Model):
    [...]
    resume = models.FileField(
        storage=import_string(settings.DEFAULT_PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE)(),
        upload_to=upload_to_unique_filename,
    )
    [...]
```

The issue is that the bucket key is hardcoded in the settings file, and since there are multiple developers + 1 staging environment, all of the junk files that are uploaded for testing/QA purposes end up in the same S3 bucket as the real production data.

One obvious solution would be to override `AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` in `staging_settings.py` and `development_settings.py` files, but that would make the production data unavailable on staging and testing instances. To make this work, we would somehow how to sync the production bucket to the dev/staging one, which I'm unsure how to do efficiently and seamlessly.

Another option would be to use local filesystem for media storage in development and staging environments. This would also require the download of substantial amount of media files, and would exclude one part of the stack (`django-storages` and S3 API) from the testing/QA process.

How to handle this? Is the mixing of testing and production media files in the same bucket even an issue (I was sure it was until I started thinking about how to handle it)? What are some best practices about separating development/staging/production cloud storages in general?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, our team use one bucket for all environments, but we add some metadata to uploaded static & media files. By this way, in order delete some kind not production S3 Objects you can just make filter using AWS API, and delete them.

It's possible by adding in settings.py:

```
ENVIRONMENT = "development/production/qa"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
   'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
   'Metadata': {
      'environment': ENVIRONMENT
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We recently addressed this issue with a custom S3Storage class that supports two buckets instead of one. Each environment writes to their own bucket which means that the production bucket doesn't get polluted with files from the temporary environments (dev, staging, QA, ...). However, if a given environment needs a resource that it can't find in its own bucket, then it automatically tries to fetch it from the production bucket. Accordingly, we do not need to duplicate tons of mostly static resources that are already available in the production bucket.

In settings.py, we add two new variables and specify a custom storage class

```
# The alternate bucket (typically the production bucket) is used as a fallback when the primary one doesn't contain the resource requested.
AWS_STORAGE_ALTERNATE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_ALTERNATE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ALTERNATE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_ALTERNATE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'

# Custom storage class
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'hello_django.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
```

Then in the custom storage class, we overwrite the `url()` method as follows

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.parse import urlencode

from django.utils.encoding import filepath_to_uri

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from storages.utils import setting


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    default_acl = 'public-read'

    def __init__(self, **settings):
        super().__init__(**settings)

    def get_default_settings(self):
        settings_dict = super().get_default_settings()
        settings_dict.update({
            "alternate_bucket_name": setting("AWS_STORAGE_ALTERNATE_BUCKET_NAME"),
            "alternate_custom_domain": setting("AWS_S3_ALTERNATE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN")
        })
        return settings_dict

    def url(self, name, parameters=None, expire=None, http_method=None):
        params = parameters.copy() if parameters else {}
        if self.exists(name):
            r = self._url(name, parameters=params, expire=expire, http_method=http_method)
        else:
            if self.alternate_bucket_name:
                params['Bucket'] = self.alternate_bucket_name
                r = self._url(name, parameters=params, expire=expire, http_method=http_method)
        return r

    def _url(self, name, parameters=None, expire=None, http_method=None):
        """
        Similar to super().url() except that it allows the caller to provide
        an alternate bucket name in parameters['Bucket']
        """
        # Preserve the trailing slash after normalizing the path.
        name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
        params = parameters.copy() if parameters else {}
        if expire is None:
            expire = self.querystring_expire

        if self.custom_domain:
            bucket_name = params.pop('Bucket', None)
            if bucket_name is None or self.alternate_custom_domain is None:
                custom_domain = self.custom_domain
            else:
                custom_domain = self.alternate_custom_domain
            url = '{}//{}/{}{}'.format(
                self.url_protocol,
                custom_domain,
                filepath_to_uri(name),
                '?{}'.format(urlencode(params)) if params else '',
            )

            if self.querystring_auth and self.cloudfront_signer:
                expiration = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=expire)
                return self.cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(url, date_less_than=expiration)

            return url

        if params.get('Bucket') is None:
            params['Bucket'] = self.bucket.name
        params['Key'] = name
        url = self.bucket.meta.client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params=params,
                                                             ExpiresIn=expire, HttpMethod=http_method)
        if self.querystring_auth:
            return url
        return self._strip_signing_parameters(url)
```

This sample [project](https://github.com/sylvainletourneau/django-docker-s3-2buckets) illustrates the approach.